# Seeking shapefile for countries of former Soviet Union

Tags: geospatial, russia

I have data at the country level for the 15 countries of the former Soviet Union but does anyone have a shapefile?

My research assistant is claiming she cannot find one.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [GADM database](http://gadm.org/country) where you can download Russian boundaries in a variety of formats suitable for QGIS and [DIVA GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) where u can download data by country. Select and download free geographic (GIS) data for any country in the world.

[Generalized political boundaries](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2001/ofr-01-104/fsucoal/html/data1.htm) of the countries comprising the Former Soviet Union

[image]

Data formats:  (Download data)

Arcview shapefile - fsucoal/views/shapes/cis.shp

[More](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2001/ofr-01-104/fsucoal/html/data1.htm)

Answer (score 3):

This is the data that comes from the MIT

https://geodata.mit.edu/catalog.html?f%5Bdc_format_s%5D%5B%5D=Shapefile&f%5Bdct_spatial_sm%5D%5B%5D=Uzbekistan&per_page=100&sort=dc_publisher_s+asc%2C+dc_title_sort+asc

For your reference : here is the information to ensure you get the right shapefiles

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Soviet_states

Answer (score 1):

A good general source for map data, including, but not limited to the political boundaries of the nations of the former Soviet Union, is [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/).

Boundaries of nations and nation-like things are under the "cultural" category, and can be downloaded at a variety of resolutions (1:10,000,000; 1:50,000,000; 1:110,000,000) and a variety of organizing principles, including sovereignty, disputed areas, internal divisions (states/provinces), transportation systems, a point-map of populated places, and more.

In addition to cultural maps, Natural Earth provides vector data for physical features and raster maps.